# Bind keyboard key (like F16) to execute command?

Tags: macos, keybindings

OK, I think this used to be an option in an older version of OSX, but I can't find in in the latest version.

How do I bind a certain key (like F16 for instance) to run a Terminal command?  I'd rather not install any additional services.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked my 10.9.5 and 10.6.8 systems, and both have this under:
    **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts**

This allows you to bind a key to a command available via the menu, either globally (for all programs) or just a specific program.

If what you want to bind isn't a standard command, you can create an Automator plug-in that becomes available via the *Services* menu of a program, so that you can bind it to a key.

Comment: That does not work for F16–F19 keys. There must be a way to override this.